# Add ability to explicitly specify "Not Willing to Relocate"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

On my Stack Overflow Careers profile, I would like to state that I am not willing to relocate. I've been contacted by a company that didn't know that, but the job required relocation.

I think the reason they didn't realize that I didn't want to relocate is because there's no option to explicitly state it. The only option that exists is to explicitly opt in to relocation possibilities.

Comment: I don't know... "not willing to relocate" should have been implied since you make a conscious decision when you declare that you do wish to relocate and where.  That is something that should be respected.

Comment: It's likely that the employer searched without specifying a location, in which case we don't use re/location as a filter.